# Bank system with accounts that use dictionary to store it but it only reads the first account

Tags: python

I'm creating a bank system with accounts but if I put 2 accounts or more the 2nd account can't be read and doesn't work in logging in only the first one that works

```
accounts = []
names = [item.get('fullname') for item in accounts]
customers = int(input("Number of customers: "))
while customers != 0:
    fullname = str(input("Input Fullname: "))
    while fullname in names:
        print('Name already exist')
        fullname = str(input("Input Fullname: "))
    else:
        pass
    pins = str(input("Please input pin of your choice: "))
    while len(pins) != 4:
        print ('Error. Only 4 digit allowed')
        pins = str(input("Please input pin of your choice: "))
    else:
        pass
    balance = int(input("Please input a value of deposit to start and account: "))
    account = [{"fullname": fullname, "pins": pins, "balance": balance}]
    accounts1 = account.copy()
    accounts.append(accounts1)
    print(accounts)
    customers -= 1
for i in range (len (accounts)):
    if name == accounts[i]['fullname'] and pin == accounts[i]['pins']:
        print('Your current balance is {} PHP'.format(accounts[i]['balance']))
    else:
        print("Account not found")
        break
```

I think it's because the array will have double bracket after appending

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: Im sorry kinda new to this

Comment: Please also fix your syntax (there is no `:` at the end of your `for` statement for example). This code cannot be run/tested as is.

Comment: `account` should be a `dict`, not a `list` with a single `dict`. There's also no reason to append a copy of the dict to `accounts`, since `account` is a brand-new `dict` with no pre-existing references to it.

Comment: What I am saying is that if your code were really what you have posted then you would get errors about your indentation.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), 
and provide a [mre] that people can paste into their environments to replicate your problem. Also, include full stack traces if you get any errors, and _fully describe the problem!_  "It doesn't work" is not an acceptable description.

Comment: Did you mean to add: `customers -= 1` at the end of your `while` loop?

Comment: yah i forgot to add it

Comment: Oh, but was that in your original code? Is that a fix for your problem?

Comment: yah its actually long code and that's the only last problem i have

Answer (score 2):

The original code had multiple errors including a wrong indentation and the missing but referenced names list.

One - at least kind of okayish working - solution based on your code is:

```
accounts = []
names = [] # add the names list
customers = int(input("Number of customers: "))
while len(accounts) != customers:
    fullname = str(input("Input Fullname: "))
    while fullname in names:
        print('Name already exist')
        fullname = str(input("Input Fullname: "))
    else:
        pass
    pins = str(input("Please input pin of your choice: "))
    while len(pins) != 4:
        print('Error. Only 4 digit allowed')
        pins = str(input("Please input pin of your choice: "))
    else:
        pass
    balance = int(
        input("Please input a value of deposit to start and account: "))
    account = {"fullname": fullname, "pins": pins, "balance": balance}
    accounts.append(account)
    names.append(fullname)
    print(accounts)

# Authenticate before staring the loop

name = str(input("Authenticate: Input your full name: "))
pin = str(input("Authenticate: Input your pin: "))
balance = None

for account in accounts:
    if name == account['fullname'] and pin == account['pins']:
        balance = account['balance']
        break
    
if balance == None:
    # then we had no match - otherwise it should be some integer
    print("Account not found")
else:
    print('Your current balance is {} PHP'.format(balance))
```